# (Java - Netbeans) I don't understand this Syntax error?

Tags: netbeans

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbtiO.gif)

I'm creating a platformer game using Netbeans and in my Sprite class I keep getting an error when trying to create my constructor. When I click on the error is just says, "Illegal start of type". I have tried so many things and I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma after the last argument to the constructor....

Comment: ahhhhhh yup it works now. Thanks, sometimes I become soo absorbed in my code I don't even notice small things like that.